# Make an image field required

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, required

I am trying to make an input required for an image upload in wordpress.
The idea is to upload an image, then crop it, and save. However, since the input tags change (you can see 2 inputs, one before uploading and one after), they become style "hidden", which makes the code not focusable and throws an error.

```
  <fieldset <?php if ($current_user->roles[0] == "contributor") {
                        # code...
                        echo "disabled";
                      } ?>>



                      <label for="postImage"><?php esc_html_e('ID Picture *:', ''); ?></label>

                        <?php esc_html_e('Image needs to be at least 250x250px', '');?>

                        <?php $baseurl = get_template_directory_uri().'/include/'; ?>

                         <div id="flash"></div>
                          <div id="ajaxresult">


                          </div>
                          <div id="files">
                          <?php
                          $photo_user = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'id_pic', true);?>
                          <?php
                          if (isset($photo_user)) {
                             echo "<img src='".esc_url($photo_user)."' id='uploadedimage' style='width:100%'>";
                          }  ?>
                         </div>
                        <span id="me" class="styleall button-small fileinput-button" style=" cursor:pointer;" >

                            <?php if(isset($photo_user)) {
                          esc_html_e('Click Here To Upload New Photo', '');
                        } else {
                          esc_html_e('Click Here To Upload Photo', '');
                        }
                        ?><input id="meimg" type="file" name="files[]" >

                        </span>


                        <div id="load"></div><span id="mestatus" ></span>


                        <div id="status"></div>
                        <div id="cropme" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small crop-me"><?php esc_html_e('CROP IMAGE', ''); ?></a></div>

                        <div id="cancelme0" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small"><?php esc_html_e('cancel', ''); ?></a></div>


                        <div id="cancelme" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small"><?php esc_html_e('cancel', 'fundingpress'); ?></a></div>
                                <br>
                             <input type="hidden" name="postImage" id="postImage" value="" />

                            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with javascript. I added the required attribute to the first input, and on the crop me button, which implies having added an image, I remove the required attribute after the onclick action, like this:

```
<div id="cropme" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small crop-me" onclick="document.getElementById('meimg').required = false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do a condition when to display the first input field and when to display the second and control it with if statement either like this or to define a boolean variable to decide what to display if true and what if false

```
 if(!isset($_POST["files"])){ 
    ?>
       <span id="me" class="styleall button-small fileinput-button" style=" cursor:pointer;" >
     <?php if(isset($photo_user)) {
                              esc_html_e('Click Here To Upload New Photo', '');
                            } else {
                              esc_html_e('Click Here To Upload Photo', '');
                            }
                            ?><input id="meimg" type="file" name="files[]" >
    }
    ?>
    </span>
    <?php
    else {
    ?>
       <div id="load"></div><span id="mestatus" ></span>


                            <div id="status"></div>
                            <div id="cropme" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small crop-me"><?php esc_html_e('CROP IMAGE', ''); ?></a></div>

                            <div id="cancelme0" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small"><?php esc_html_e('cancel', ''); ?></a></div>


                            <div id="cancelme" style="display:none;"><a class="button-small"><?php esc_html_e('cancel', 'fundingpress'); ?></a></div>
                                    <br>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="postImage" id="postImage" value="" />

                                </fieldset>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I tried something that worked